# How to send email with dataframe as attachment using sendgrid api in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Hey i need to send email notification whenever an event happens, i am able to send the email but i am not sure how to attach dataframe as an attachment to it.

```
def send_mail(content):

    # Defining Email Body and Notificaion type.    
    html_content='Hi Team,</br><strong>{}</br></br>Thanks</strong></br></br>'.format(content)

    # Defining Email_Format.
    message = Mail(
        from_email='XXXXXX@.com',
        to_emails=['XXXXXX@.com'],
        subject='test',
        html_content=html_content)
    
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        response = sg.send(message)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e.message)
    
    return None
```

I am able send notification through above code, but i need to attach dataframe as an attachment to that mail, i have no clue how to attach it.

df_to_attach. --- I need to attach this dataframe as an attachment

```
Id   Name
1    rick
2    John
3    uran
4    Turan
```

Comment: convert the dataframe to csv and then attach it as file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

As Joshua suggested in the comment, convert your dataframe to CSV format and then attach as a CSV file. Something like this:

```py
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType, Disposition, ContentId)
import base64

def send_mail(content, dataframe):

    # Defining Email Body and Notificaion type.    
    html_content='Hi Team,</br><strong>{}</br></br>Thanks</strong></br></br>'.format(content)

    # Defining Email_Format.
    message = Mail(
        from_email='XXXXXX@.com',
        to_emails=['XXXXXX@.com'],
        subject='test',
        html_content=html_content)
  
    base64_csv = base64.b64encode(dataframe.to_csv(index=False).encode())
    message.attachment = Attachment(FileContent(base64_csv),
                                    FileName('dataframe.csv'),
                                    FileType('text/csv'),
                                    Disposition('attachment'),
                                    ContentId('datafrane'))
    
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        response = sg.send(message)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e.message)
    
    return None
```

Comment: "Attachment(FileContent(base64_csv)" where is this Attachment object is coming from?

Comment: i am getting this error : AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: The `Attachment` should have been imported from the `sendgrid.helpers.mail`, apologies. I've updated the code. As for your second comment, the only thing that calls `message` is in the exception handler, which was in your original code. Should that be `logging.error(str(e))` instead?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i got another error: ERROR:root:Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: Ah, I think you need to decode the base64 again so that it’s a string, not bytes. `base64_csv = base64.b64encode(dataframe.to_csv(index=False).encode()).decode()`